# generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes in ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, block

If I run the following in a project where ARC is enabled the completion handler never fires. But without ARC it works as expected. What am I missing here?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"];
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, 
                                                   CGImageRef im, 
                                                   CMTime actualTime, 
                                                   AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, 
                                                   NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"completion handler");
};

generator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: Having the same issue... /sigh. Will let you know if I figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Michael pointing out that generator doesn't get retained, if you simply 'use' the generator var inside the completion block, everything will work.

So I guess the answer is...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"];
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, 
                                                   CGImageRef im, 
                                                   CMTime actualTime, 
                                                   AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, 
                                                   NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"make sure generator is used in this block and it'll work %@", generator);
};

generator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes does not retain the generator. Make generator a member variable of your instance and assign to it. As soon as I did that, it started working. The code will look something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"];
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
[generator_ cancelAllCGImageGeneration];
generator_ = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator_.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, 
                                                   CGImageRef im, 
                                                   CMTime actualTime, 
                                                   AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, 
                                                   NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"completion handler");
};

generator_.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
[generator_ generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: Traditionally, underscores come before the variable name.

Comment: We've been using the Google Objective-C style guide internally which suggests trailing underscores: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Variable_Names Traditionally Apple has reserved the leading underscore for private framework variables.

Answer (score 0):

The image generator *definitely* does **not** get retained by the framework. Not sure how often Apple Programming Guide gets updated, but you can read that in AV Foundation Prog. Guide, in [Generating a Sequence of Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH7-SW7) quite clearly:

> > In addition, you must ensure that you retain the image generator 
> >     until it has finished creating the images.