# iOS Thumbnail from Amazon S3 MP4/MOV URL

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, thumbnails

I have several videos uploaded on Amazon S3 bucket. I want to display the videos in a list format in an iOS application along with the thumbnail.

Suppose the url is https://testurlatamzons3/mybucket/somefile.mp4 and I want to get the thumbnail from the URL without actually downloading or streaming the file.

I have seen certain examples and I am able to download the UIImage and display it on the UIImageView. The example I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906620/generatecgimagesasynchronouslyfortimes-in-arc)
But for a 350MB file on amazon s3, it takes around 1.9mb of data transfer just to get the thumbnail. Is there a more optimized or a different approach to getting the thumbnails for the mp4/mov files hosted on Amazon S3

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could get thumbnails using AVFoundation with any time, any size you want:

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:yourVideoUrl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, 
                                                   CGImageRef im, 
                                                   CMTime actualTime, 
                                                   AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, 
                                                   NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"make sure generator is used in this block and it'll work %@", generator);
};

generator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Comment: ^ This is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options:

1. To have some API which does what you want and returns the URL of the thumbnail image to your application
2. To download just a small part of the video and grab a frame from it but this depends on the format of your video, maybe this could help for MP4 videos

https://github.com/ohminteractive/OHMTagLib